# Reading a barcode in an image in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any barcode reader library for PHP? I was trying to make a mobile app where the user takes a picture of a barcode and process it.

Unfortunately, Corona SDK, which I am using for my development, only supports a library like that for the enterprise license, which is insanely expensive.

So, I have been thinking that the best way to get the barcode from an image is to send the image file to my server, process it using PHP, and send back the data of the scanned barcode back to the mobile app.

I've been googling for a while but still no luck, or maybe it's there but I just missed it. Can anyone give a link to me?

Comment: try reading this http://www.synet.sk/php/en/280-barcode-reader-scanner-in-php

Comment: Ok thanks, be back after reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the zxing library.
You can download it from here:
[a link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list)!

May be even this can help:
http://phpmyweb.net/2012/07/18/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/

Comment: it's an android app, I'm using Corona SDK. I'm not sure this is going to help.

Comment: Check if this can be useful to you: [link]?(http://alandix.com/code/barcode-reader/)